# What is this question on random variables asking?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

The question states:

> A random variable $X$ is called symmetric about 0 if for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $\mathbb P(X \geq x) = \mathbb P(X \leq -x)$.
>
> Prove that if $X$ is symmetric about 0, then for all $t > 0$, its
>   distribution function $F$ satisfies the following relations: (I'm only
>   going to give one example so I can do the rest myself)
>
> a) $\mathbb P(|X|\leq t) = 2F(t)-1$.

How do I prove this?

And also what does it mean that the random variable $X$ is symmetric about 0?

Comment: Hint: $F(t) = \mathbb P(X \leq t)$.

Comment: @cardinal So you're saying $\Bbb P$(|X|=<t) = 2$\Bbb P$(|X|=<t)-1??

Comment: No. It's how I wrote it. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just not following this..

Comment: It's ok. What properties about probability do you know? For example, do you know that $\mathbb P(A) = 1 - \mathbb P(A^c)$ for any event $A$? Do you know that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $\mathbb P(A \cup B) = \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B)$? I've shown you the relationship between $F(t)$ and $\mathbb P(X \leq t)$. Try to use properties similar to the above by rewriting the event $\{|X| \leq t\}$ in different ways where you can use these properties. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

$$
LHS=P(|X| \leq t)=P(-t \leq X \leq t)=F(t)-F(-t)
$$
by symmetry, $F(-t)=P(X \leq -t)=P(X \geq t)=1-F(t)$, hence
$$
LHS=F(t)-1+F(t)=2F(t)-1=RHS
$$

Comment: *Careful!* The last "equality" on your first line is not (necessarily) an equality.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh now I see what I'm looking for. Very big thanks to @cardinal and Alex, thats greatly appreciated!! I was looking for a numerical anser this whole time.

Comment: @cardinal: thanks, I sort of assumed $X$ is absolutely continuous